# Android, Yellow color (#FFFCCA) looks REALLY light in device screen

Tags: android, colors, screen

The screens on the devices we have seem to have a slight greenish cast, so a color that looks fine on my monitor and on an iPhone, looks *really bad* on a physical device (Nexus One, Droids). Is there a formula or something to convert base colors into something that we need to do to make colors (presumably, mostly yellows) look acceptable in most devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we're now testing in a Galaxy Tab 10.1, and that color looks just fine. I guess it's just the Nexus One screen, and there's no real fix for this.

Comment: You should try the standard Color.YELLOW (#FFFF00) on a Nexus S for a new meaning of greenish.

Answer (score 0):

Even on my computer it doesn't look yellow for me:

http://www.colorhunter.com/color/FFFCCA

Comment: Right, right, it's not pure yellow ;)  . Yellow-ish. Let's see if I can post photographic evidence. Edit - Ok, that's weird, the camera is making the colors look better than in real life. Sigh.